# Struts1 tags to Struts2 tags

Tags: struts2

The Web application which i am currently working uses Struts1, now i am migrating this application to Struts2.

The below tags are Struts1 tags, Need to modify this tags to Struts2.

```html
<bean:define id="recordPerPageList" name="searchForm" property="recordPerPageList" type="java.util.Collection"/>

<td class="formPromptTd"><html:hidden property="action" value="<%=actionFirst%>"/><input name="quickSearchFlag" type="hidden" value=""></td>

<html:image property="searchButton" src="<%=searchImage%>"/>
```

Could any one provide the Struts 2 equivalent tags ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: What I mean: there is documentation out there, explaining what these tags mean. Have you researched that? What have you tried with struts2, and what are the problems you are running into then?!

Comment: It wouldn't look like anything, because it's unnecessary, almost always. There's always `<s:set>`. Maybe check out the S2 docs.

Comment: I can replace <bean:define> with <s:set> ,Also could you please tell me the equivalent of other tags.

Comment: <html:image property="searchButton" src="<%=searchImage%>"/>Whats the equivalent tag in Struts2

Answer (score 0):

```html
The <s:fieldError> tag would be the closest equivalent for <html:message>
<html:messages id="userName" property="userName">
<s:fielderror fieldName="userName" />
```

The  tag would be the closest equivalent for